# Skip console error continue execution linux php

Tags: java, php, json, linux

I am trying to execute java jar file command in php. I want run it in Linux.
This is what i am using in windows

```
chdir('C:\Users\usename\Desktop\foldername');
$output = shell_exec('java -jar jar1.jar C:\Users\usename\Desktop\foldername\resource.json');
```

**This is what i am using in linux**

```
chdir('linux path');
$output = shell_exec('java -jar jar1.jar linux_path\resource.json');
```

if i execute the same command in terminal it works fine in both windows and linux.
        But if i execute through my php code, i am getting some logger issue.
        How to resolve it?
        Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error in log ??

Comment: main ERROR unable to locate appender 'filelogger' for logger config . This error comes in terminal also but after that execution continues and we can get result.with PHP file this error shows and execution stops.No result :(

Comment: I am not sure but just give it a try `$output = shell_exec('(echo status ; sleep 0.1) | java -jar jar1.jar linux_path\resource.json'); ` and see

Comment: Still the same error @MASIDDIQUI